# Manually triggering IHostedService scheduled tasks

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET Core API with recurring email sender scheduled task in it. I've found various ways to implement it and used one of them. It is working every minute as expected, but I don't know if this is the right way to create.

I am storing it in the database table like (Id, TaskName, IsActive, LastStartedDate) for checking if it is active or not. But right now I can do it in the task itself, not before running it. This is my first problem.

The second problem is, that I want to manually trigger it for various reasons sometimes. I can't do this either. This is my main problem. I don't know if this is possible though.

Here is my code:

**EmailSenderTask.cs:**

```
public class EmailSenderTask : ScheduledProcessor
{
    public EmailSenderTask(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory) : base(serviceScopeFactory) { }

    protected override string Schedule => "*/1 * * * *";

    public override Task ProcessInScope(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var context = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
        var emailSender = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEmailSender>();

        var task = context.ScheduleTask.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SystemName.Equals("EmailSenderTask"));

        if (task.Active)
        {
            // Doing some stuff...

            task.LastStartDate = DateTime.Now;
            context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

**ScheduledProcessor.cs:**

```
public abstract class ScheduledProcessor : ScopedProcessor
{
    private CrontabSchedule _schedule;
    private DateTime _nextRun;
    protected abstract string Schedule { get; }
    public ScheduledProcessor(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory) : base(serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _schedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse(Schedule);
        _nextRun = _schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        do
        {
            var now = DateTime.Now;
            var nextrun = _schedule.GetNextOccurrence(now);
            if (now > _nextRun)
            {
                await Process();
                _nextRun = _schedule.GetNextOccurrence(DateTime.Now);
            }
            await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken); //5 seconds delay
        }
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);
    }
}
```

**ScopedProcessor.ts:**

```
public abstract class ScopedProcessor : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public ScopedProcessor(IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory) : base()
    {
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task Process()
    {
        using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            await ProcessInScope(scope.ServiceProvider);
        }
    }

    public abstract Task ProcessInScope(IServiceProvider serviceProvider);
}
```

**BackgroundService.cs:**

```
public abstract class BackgroundService : IHostedService
{
    private Task _executingTask;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _stoppingCts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

        if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            return _executingTask;
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public virtual async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (_executingTask == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            _stoppingCts.Cancel();
        }
        finally
        {
            await Task.WhenAny(_executingTask, Task.Delay(Timeout.Infinite, cancellationToken));
        }
    }

    protected virtual async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        do
        {
            await Process();

            await Task.Delay(5000, stoppingToken); //5 seconds delay
        }
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested);
    }

    protected abstract Task Process();
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, EmailSenderTask>();
```

How can I check if the task is active

Answer (score 0):

> I am storing it in the database table like (Id, TaskName, IsActive, LastStartedDate) for checking if it is active or not. But right now I can do it in the task itself, not before running it. This is my first problem.

What you're looking for is a "lease". While it's *possible* to store leases in a database, it's also not very easy. It's much easier to use a data storage that has delete-after-expiry semantics, like CosmosDb or Redis.

Then, when your background service fires (or is manually triggered), it try-acquires the lease, and if the lease is already taken, it skips processing for that occurrence.

> The second problem is, that I want to manually trigger it for various reasons sometimes. I can't do this either. This is my main problem. I don't know if this is possible though.

There's nothing built-in to .NET for this. What I've done is to add a separate interface for periodic background tasks that I want to execute manually, and then update `Program.cs` to manually execute the task that's specified on the command line if it's running as a console app (as opposed to a service). A bit tedious, but doable.

Side note: I find scope-per-service-lifetime surprising; it makes all scoped dependencies singletons. What I found find less surprising is a scope-per-occurrence.